# Creating a JavaScript quiz App (pseudo code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

Can someone check to see if I'm on the right track, this is my attempt at my first web application I've been trying to different approaches, but each time I get about half way through to find out I'm complicating things so this time I'm writing pseudo code and use that as a guide to help me accomplish my goal, I just need to know if my approach is correct:

This is my html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="quiz">
        <h3 class="question"></h3> display question
        <p class="choices"></p> display choices



    </div>
</div>
```

This is the array:

```
            var questions = [{
            question: "What is my Favourite Movie?",
            choices: ["The Matrix", "Star Wars", "The Godfather", "Django: Unchained"],
            correctAnswer: 0
        }, {
            question: "What was my Dream Job when I was a mere child?",
            choices: ["Programmer", "Footballer", "Super Hero", "Zoologist"],
            correctAnswer: 2
        }, {
            question: "How long did it take me to make this Web Application?",
            choices: ["12hours", "6 hours", "7hours", "10hours"],
            correctAnswer: 3
        }, {
            question: "Why have I built this Web Application?",
            choices: ["Boredom", "Display my Programming Skills", "Somebodys request", "......"],
            correctAnswer: 1
        }, {
            question: "Which Musical Instrument do I play?",
            choices: ["Bongos", "Piano", "Trumpet", "Harmonica"],
            correctAnswer: 0
        }];
```

and this is my pseudo code:

1.
display the first question
and the first set of choices
to that question

2.
when the user clicks a choice:
if choice === correctAnswer
add one point

else 
do nothing?

if the currentQuestion < question.length
then move to the next question
and set of choices,

else

message alert("you reach end of quiz");
you got correctAnswer; //display score:

Does this look like the right plan?

Thanks all help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your array of objects stored as `questions` looks good.

A possible and more real-world approach would be to save your array of objects as a `json` file here: myjson.com and then call it via `AJAX` request.

If you decide to go that route, you would have to place quotes around the `question` key and `correctAnswer` key as well as on their corresponding values for it to be picked up as `json'.

Once you save it correctly it will give you an `api` url endpoint. You will need that for your `AJAX` call.

You could also just have a bare bones index.html file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quizstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="output"></div>



<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Then in your script.js file:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
// this allows us to keep it as a global value
var myObj = '';
    page = 0;
loadQuestions();

function loadQuestions() {
  // http request
  // this will allow you to pull in
  // the questions from the api that
  // your questions or data is stored in
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
  a.open("GET", "<api-url-endpoint>", true); // opened request with address with
  a.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (a.readyState == 4) {
      myObj = JSON.parse(a.responseText);
      page = 1;
      buildQuiz(1);
    }
  }
  a.send();
}

function buildQuiz(page){
  for (var i in myObj) {
    var myQuestion = myObj[page - 1].question;
    var myCorrect = myObj[page - 1].question;
    var questionHolder = '';
    for(var i in myObj[page - 1].correctAnswer){
      questionHolder += '<div class="col-sm-6">'
    }
    console.log();
  }

}
```

You are going to want to use a `for..in` loop and not a `for` loop the way your spec suggests in your "pseudo code" section.